# Unit Testing Angular.js with $httpBackend and $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test an Angular.js controller. I am actually testing making a call to a Mock Backend, which returns some dummy data. When I get the data, I call a service method, passing the result as a parameter. 
Now, that service is injected into the controller which I am trying to test, and there is a $scope.$watch method, which looks for the values updated in the service, and sets the data on the scope of the controller.

```
  $scope.$watch(function(){
      return FileService.getFileData();
    }, function (newValue) {
    self.fileData = newValue;
    self.displayData = [].concat(self.fileData);
  });
```

Test:

```
describe('Filebrowser', function() {
  var scope;
  var controller;
  beforeEach(module('oide.filebrowser'));

  describe('FilebrowserController Test', function() {
    var httpBackend;
    var http;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $http){
      // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
      httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $controller;
      http = $http

      // Mock FileService
      var currentDirectory = ['/', 'home', 'saurabh'];
      var currentFile = '/home/saurabh/testfile';
      var rootDirectory = '/home/saurabh';
      var volume_info = {
        'percent': '10',
        'used': '10',
        'size': '100'
      };
      var fileData;
      var groups = ['saurabh', 'sudo', 'adm'];

      mockFileService = {
        getCurrentDirectory: function() {
          return currentDirectory;
        },
        getFileData: function() {
          return currentFile;
        },
        getRootDirectory: function() {
          return rootDirectory;
        },
        getVolumeInfo: function() {
          return volume_info;
        },
        setFileData: function(data) {
          fileData = data;
        },
        getFileData: function(){
          return fileData;
        }
      };

      // Mock FilesystemService
      mockFilesystemService = {
        getGroups: function() {
          return groups;
        }
      };
      // Mock FiletreeService
      mockFiletreeService = {};
      controller = $controller(
        'FilebrowserController as ctrl', {
          $scope: scope,
          FileService: mockFileService,
          FilesystemService: mockFilesystemService,
          FBFiletreeService: mockFiletreeService,
          $modal: {}
        });
        scope.ctrl = controller;
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should fetch files for a particular directory', function(){
      http.get('/filebrowser/filetree/a/dir')
      .success(function(data){
        mockFileService.setFileData(data);
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(scope.ctrl.fileData);
          expect(scope.ctrl.fileData).toBeDefined();
        }, 1);
      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
      httpBackend.whenGET('/filebrowser/filetree/a/dir').respond(function(){
        var files = [{
          "filepath": "/home/saurabh/file1",
          "filename": "file1",
          "group": "saurabh",
          "is_accessible": true,
          "perm": "-rw-rw-r--",
          "perm_string": "664",
          "size": "0.0 KiB",
          "type": "file"
        }, {
          "filepath": "/home/saurabh/file2",
          "filename": "file2",
          "group": "root",
          "is_accessible": false,
          "perm": "-rw-r--r--",
          "perm_string": "644",
          "size": "0.0 KiB",
          "type": "file"
        },
        {
          "filepath": "/home/saurabh/file3",
          "filename": "file3",
          "group": "saurabh",
          "is_accessible": true,
          "perm": "-rw-rw-r--",
          "perm_string": "664",
          "size": "0.0 KiB",
          "type": "file"
        }];
        return [200, files];
      });
      httpBackend.flush();
      // });
    });

  });
});
```

In my test, I am trying to check if the fileData variable has been defined or not. There is a console log statement, which does output the fileData variable to the console. However, the expect statement fails with the following error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR
        TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.results_.addResult')
        at /home/saurabh/workspace/OIDE/oide/client/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2348
```

Two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is this the right way to test using a mock HTTP backend?

Comment: Moving the expect to after the call to flush() fixes the issue, and makes the setTimeout unnecessary. I still would like to know if this method is the right way or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is the 'right' way or not might just be a matter of opinion, but here goes mine:

1.)I can't see all of your controller code, but usually you don't need to write the actual http.get call in your test as you've done here, that's your controller's job. Your test should instantiate the controller (or do whatever your controller is listening for) to trigger that http call and then you just assert expectations from that (like did it properly set your $scope variables).

2.) Why is this service call `FileService.getFileData()` wrapped in a `$scope.watch()`? If your answer is that you want to only trigger this call after a previous successful http call, then you should be wrapping the second call in a promise (`.then` or`.success`) after the first call.
Ex:

```
function makeServiceCalls() {
  mockFileService.getCurrentDirectory()
  .success( function() {
    FileService.getFileData()
    .then(// do more stuff);
  })
  .error( function() {
  // wah-wahhhh
  }
}
```

Passing unit tests can be tricky. You should make sure that you test the negative case first before you consider it valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
That Fileservice.getFileData() call is wrapped in a $scope.watch, as the Fileservice is being used in another controller, which sets the values which are being retrieved

Comment: The actual HTTP call is written in in a service. So should that service also be injected? Or should I mock that service with the HTTP call I have written in the test?

Comment: Yes, inject the service in the test. Then you can remove all of that mock service code that you have in the test as well. You always want your unit tests to cover the code that's written in your app (controllers/services/factories) and not code that you write in the test.